# Python BS4 Not Retrieving Results

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Using the below code, I am able to fetch "soup" without an issue. My goal is to ultimately fetch the title within the soup object, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it. In addition to below, I've also tried various iterations of soup['results'], soup.results, soup.get_text().results .. etc and not sure how to get to it. I can, of course, do soup.get_text() ... (some kind of search function for the string "title," but feel like there has to be a built-in method for this.

```
55)get_title()
     54     ipdb.set_trace()
---> 55     title = soup.html.head.title.string
     56     title = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+',' ', title)

ipdb> type(soup)
<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>
ipdb> soup.title
ipdb> print soup.title
None
ipdb> soup
{"status":"OK","copyright":"Copyright (c) 2018 The New York Times Company. All Rights Reserved.","section":"home","last_updated":"2018-01-07T06:19:00-05:00","num_results":42,"results":[{"section":"Briefing","subsection":"",**"title":"Trump, Palestinians, Golden Globes: Your Weekend Briefing"**, ....
```

Code

```
from __future__ import division

import regex as re
import string
import urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from cookielib import CookieJar
import ipdb

PARSER_TYPE = 'html.parser'

def get_title(url):
    cj = CookieJar()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    p = opener.open(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(p.read(), PARSER_TYPE) # This loads fine
    ipdb.set_trace()
    title = soup.html.head.title.string # This is sad
    title = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+',' ', title)
    return title
```

Comment: show us the HTML you're trying to scrape (the part that contains the title)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at what `p.read()` returns. You will find that it is not HTML, it is a JSON string. You can't use a HTML parser to successfully parse JSON, however, you can use a JSON parser such as the one provided in the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) package.

```
import json

p = opener.open(url)
response = json.loads(p.read())
```

Following this `response` will reference a dictionary. You can then use dictionary access methods to extract a particular piece of data:

```
title = response['results'][0]['title']
```

Note here that `response['results']` is itself a `list` so you need to get the first element of that list (at least for the example that you've shown). `response['results'][0]` then gives a second nested dictionary that contains the data that you want. Look that up with the `title` key.

Since the results are contained in a list you might need to iterate over that list to process each result:

```
for result in response['results']:
    print(result['title'])
```

If some results do not have title keys you can use `dict.get()` to perform the lookup without raising an exception:

```
for result in response['results']:
    print(result.get('title'))
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you so much.